# change last attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** I use skrollr js to create parallax website but because we don't know the height of section because section height depend on the content so what I need is find the last attribute and change number value only with section height.

for example:

for section 1 the data-800 (attr) will be `data-800="position:fixed;top:-$('section 1').height;"`

for section 2 the data-900 (attr) will be `data-900="position:fixed;top:-$('section 2').height;"`

**my goal is get height for any section and set it in the attribute**

```js
$('section').attr('data-800', 'position:fixed;top:-' + $('.section').height());
var s = skrollr.init({
    render: function(data) {
        console.log(data.curTop);
    }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}

.grad0 {
    height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background-color: #FFAAAA;
    
 background-image: url(https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/profile/profile-bg-8ff33bd9518be912289d4620cb48f21eb5c9a2e0b9577484126cfe10a5fb354f.svg);
}

.grad1 {
  position:fixed;
  background-color: #00FF00
}

.grad2 {
  position:fixed;
  top:800px;
  background-color: #0000FF
}
.grad3 {
  position:fixed;
  top:1200px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: #00FFFF
}
section {
  width:100%;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top:150px;
}
```

```html
<section class="grad0 w60" data-0="top:0px;" data-400="top:0px;"  data-800="position:fixed;top:-400px;">
  <img src="http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chuck/lennapg/len_top.jpg" data-0="left:0px" data-400="left:1600px;">
</section>
<section class="grad1" data-400="position:fixed;top:638px;" data-900="position:fixed;top:-400px;">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</section>
<section class="grad2"  data-0="position:fixed;top:800px;" data-400="position:fixed;top:800px;" data-800="position:fixed;top:000px;">
    content
</section>
<section class="grad3"  data-0="position:fixed;top:1200px;" data-400="position:fixed;top:1200px;" data-800="position:fixed;top:400px;">
    content
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: `top` requires units to be a valid value.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

As you commented for each of the last data attribute should be targeted:

```js
$('section').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  var dataset = Object.keys(this.dataset);
  $.each(dataset, function(i, item) {
    if (i === dataset.length - 1) {
      $this.attr('data-' + dataset[i], 'position:fixed;top:-' + $this.height());
      console.log($this[0].dataset);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="grad0 w60" data-0="top:0px;" data-400="top:0px;" data-800="position:fixed;top:-400px;">
  <img src="http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chuck/lennapg/len_top.jpg" data-0="left:0px" data-400="left:1600px;">
</section>
<section class="grad1" data-400="position:fixed;top:638px;" data-900="position:fixed;top:-400px;">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</section>
<section class="grad2" data-0="position:fixed;top:800px;" data-400="position:fixed;top:800px;" data-800="position:fixed;top:000px;">
  content
</section>
<section class="grad3" data-0="position:fixed;top:1200px;" data-400="position:fixed;top:1200px;" data-800="position:fixed;top:400px;">
  content
</section>
```

Comment: thank you, I need to write flexible code to find the last attribute for any section and replace the top value with the section height

Comment: @MichaelNeas you can use the snippet added.